# Asymptotic equivalence for complex valued functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, asymptotics

We know that two functions $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent if $\displaystyle{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1}$. There are other equivalent definitions for this. My primary concern is that whether the theory can be extended to complex valued functions. I am not being able to find good references or articles that confirm the fact. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know, but just thinking about it you'd have to consider how do you define the limit as $z$ goes to $\infty$.   There's only one path in the real numbers, but in the complex numbers you can go unbounded in any direction

Comment: Yeah thats true. But what if the limit does really exist as z tends to infinity? Then no such discrepancy arises

Comment: What do you mean by as $z$ tends to infinity?  The only way I could think of defining that is on any path in which $|z|\to \infty$.  Math on that would be annoying.

Comment: Yeah. But can't it be done considering the behavior of the function f(1/w)/g(1/w) as w tends to zero? Surely there are many ways in which w approaches zero. Just an idea.

Comment: @Alan The notion of $\lim_{z\to\infty}$ in complex analysis is perfectly standard. Annoying or not, yes it means $|z|\to\infty$.

Comment: You're wondering whether _what_ theory can be extended? So far you've mentioned nothing but one definition...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sounds sensible enough.  I had very little complex analysis, and now I'm stuck in teaching remedial math.  Trying to keep my brain stretched out here!